# Android | Unmarshalling Unknown Type while using Parcelable Data in Bundles

Tags: android, exception, unmarshalling, parcelable

I have a Problem with Parcelable Data in an ArrayList sending via two Activities using Android.Bundle

I have two Activities (A and B).

In Aaaa.class:

```
ArrayList<Model> mModelList = new ArrayList<Model>
//Fill ArrayList with a few Model-Objects

Bundle mBundle = new Bundle;
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Aaaa.this, Bbbb.class);

mBundle.putParcelableArrayList("models", mModelList);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);

startActivity(mIntent);
```

In Bbbb.class:

```
Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<Model> = mBundle.getParcelableArrayList("models");
```

The Model.class is implementing Parcelable.

So, the Problem is.
When I fill the ArrayList (in Aaaa.class) and put it to the Bundle, I can see that the Bundle contains the varios Objects from the List.
When I then try to fill the List in Bbbb.class a Exception is Thrown.

```
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test/test.activities.Bbbb}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@405585d0: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7667810 at offset 144
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@405585d0: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7667810 at offset 144
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1913)
    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2092)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1536)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1867)
    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1144)
    at test.activities.Bbbb.onCreate(Bbbb.java:52)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    ... 11 more
```

Line52 is

```
ArrayList<Model> = mBundle.getParcelableArrayList("models");
```

I have absolutly no Idea where is the Problem here, the Model.class is working fine with other Bundle - Intents.

Update:

The Model Class as followed.

```
public class Model implements Parceleble{

  private String name;
  private String address;

  public Model(Parcel parcel){
  }
  public Model(){
  }
  public Model(String name, String address){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }

  //Getter and Setter

  //equals, HashCode, toString (autoGenerated from Idea)

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i){
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeString(address);
  }

  public void readFromParcel(Parcel parcel){
    this.name = parcel.readString();
    this.address = parcel.readString();
  }

  public static Parcelable.Creator<Model> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Model>(){
  @Override
  public Model createFromParcel(Parcel parcel){
    return new Model(parcel);
  }

  @Override
  public Model[] new Array(int size){
    return new Model[size]
  }
};
}
```

Comment: Can you post you Model class?

Comment: @yorkw Postet the Model.class as you wished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Parceleble implementation doesn't look quite correct to me, check out the sample code in [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to see what are the required method/constructor that need to be overridden:

```
... ...

// ==================== Parcelable ====================
public int describeContents() {
  return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
  parcel.writeString(name);
  parcel.writeString(address);
}

private Model(Parcel in) {
  name = in.readString();
  address = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Model> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Model>() {
  public Model createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    return new Model(in);
  }

  public Model[] newArray(int size) {
    return new Model[size];
  }
};

... ...
```

Try this code and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi @yorkw thank you very much for your response. The Problem was in the implementation of the model, espacially in the parcel-Creator (private Model(parcel in)).

Comment: I don't see how is this block of code different from the Model class code provided by the OP, or is it that it was updated later?

Comment: @ChristianGarcía OP's implementation is missing the method `describeContents` which is quite important since it explains about the contents of the parcel (Objects inside it). I hope you are clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a long time to discover what is that and I think there is a bug. **Let me explain**:

If your Model has string fields the Android can't recovery them very well on the method

```
Parcel.readString()
```

He tries to convert the string and give to you an unknown type like an unknow character. Just doing a test, if you use a parcelable model without string fields, it occours perfectly.

I don't know what to do and why it occours with string fields.

To solve the problem, I thought passing a list of model objects to the next activity using database, perhaps it don't be the better idea but I don't have another.